# Can I use gnu grep to search for unmatched parens (and similar)?

Tags: grep, gnu

I write text files in the MoinMoin Wiki markup language in a text editor (emacs). When I mis-place one of the special tags my whole page gets mangled with the wrong formatting -- or worse. I always close a formatting element on the same line where I opened it.

Can I use **gnu grep** to find mismatching Wiki-tags on a line? Like:

- `<<` macroname `(` params `)` `>>`
- `backtick` code `backtick`
- `''` double quotes for *italics* `''`  -- probably difficult
- `'''` triple quotes for **bold** `'''` -- probably difficult

I normally do not nest tags. So there is no "bold code" or "bold italics".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No in general. grep is line oriented tools and regex is less powered then context free gramma.
If you try write:

```
grep -v '<<[^>]>>' <file
```

you miss in match:

```
<<good>>  <<bad>d>
```

But you already use **Emacs** and some checks already included:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>check-parens</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>!

If you read http://moinmo.in/HelpOnParsers you can learn that writing parser for MoinMoin is hard task.